# Defined undefined result mysql_free_result

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to free a a mysqli result, the variable is defined, then is undefined, I don't know what happen, but is too strange.

```
public function __destruct() {
    if(isset($this->result) && is_a($this->result, "mysqli_result")) {
        var_dump($this->result);
        mysqli_free_result($this->$result);
    }
    mysqli_close($this->conexion);
}
```

If isset and is a mysqli_result type it enters in the condition, it enter and I get this:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\Tell Yourself\app\model\Database.class.php on line 22
```

This is the full class:

```
abstract class Database {
protected $conexion;
protected $result;

public function __construct() {
    if(!isset($this->conexion)) {
        if($this->conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tellYourself")) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            echo "No se ha podido realizar conexion con la base de datos: ".mysqli_connect_error();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public function __destruct() {
    if(isset($this->result) && is_a($this->result, "mysqli_result")) {
        var_dump($this->result);
        mysqli_free_result($this->$result);
    }
    mysqli_close($this->conexion);
}

protected function query($query) {
    if($this->result = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $query)) {
        /*if(is_a($this->result, "mysqli_result")) {
            $this->result = mysqli_fetch_object($this->result);
        }*/
        return $this->result;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

And this is the child:

```
require_once("app/model/Database.class.php");

class User extends Database {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function __destruct() {
    parent::__destruct();
}

public function login($email, $password) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexion, $email);
    $password = md5($password);

    $loginQuery = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE email='$email' and password='$password';";
    if($result = $this->query($loginQuery)) {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
        $_SESSION["username"] = $result->username;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function register($username, $email, $password) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexion, $username);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexion, $email);
    $password = md5($password);
    $activationCode = md5($username.rand(0, 100));

    $registerQuery = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password');";
    if($this->query($registerQuery)) {
        $activationCodeQuery = "INSERT INTO user_emailconfirm(userId, activeCode) VALUES(".mysqli_insert_id($this->conexion).", '$activationCode');";
        if($this->query($activationCodeQuery)) {
            return array("userID" => mysqli_insert_id($this->conexion), "activationCode" => $activationCode);
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function activateUser($activationCode, $userID) {
    $activateUserQuery = "SELECT userId, activeCode FROM user_emailconfirm WHERE userId='$userID' and activeCode='$activationCode';";
    if($result = $this->query($activateUserQuery)) {
        var_dump($result);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $activateUserQuery = "UPDATE user_emailconfirm SET confirmed=1 WHERE userId='$userID' and activeCode='$activationCode';";
            if($this->query($activateUserQuery)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

The finality of the code is to free a result when it has data.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but if you just copied the code above, i saw an error:
Change the following line (in your destructor):

```
mysqli_free_result($this->$result);
```

to

```
mysqli_free_result($this->result);
```

Remove the $-sign before 'result' in the mysqli_free_result() argument.
Otherwise, php interpret the property as dynamically variable and it is undefined.

I hope it fix the error and i could help :)